# LTspice error: Missing model definition

Tags: ltspice

I have written the following simple curve tracer simulator:

```
LTSpice As A Curve Tracer: Diode I-V Characteristics
*
* Circuit Description
*
VD N001 0 0V
D1 N001 0 {modelname}
*
* diode model statements with aliasing in order to facilitate stepping
* NB that 1mA_diode does not override the breakdown defaults, so we get no breakdown 
* in its case (since VZK is infinity in the default case)
*
.model 1mA_diode D(Is=100pA n=1.679)
.model 1 ako:1mA_diode
.model bkdwn_diode  D(Is=100pA n=1.679 BV=10V IBV=1nA)
.model 2 ako:bkdwn_diode
*
* Analysis Requests
*
.DC VD -15V 800mV 10mV
.STEP param modelname LIST 1 2
.backanno
.end
```

However, I continue to get the error shown in the picture below. This is fairly maddening seeing as I seem to be doing the same thing with 1 and 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: The line **D1 N001 0 {modelname}** is not right. Try changing it to **D1 N001 0 1** or **D1 N001 0 2**. "{modelname}" is the name of the models you defined below with the ako directive.

Comment: @qrk But the entire point is that I am trying to parametrize modelname and then .STEP through it?

Comment: @EE18 Does [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/308287/95619) help?

Comment: Hmm, [it works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mzur.png). I'm only speculating but, given the grey background, is this the schematic editor, or the text editor? I used the former, in which case `.backanno` and `.end` are useless (they are automatically added), but the latter also works. If you're in the schematic editor, do you have other elements placed that might "collide"? If it's the text editor, maybe it's a bug in the Mac version (I have the Windows version)?

Comment: I am in the text editor, so perhaps it is a bug indeed, or else some invisible character somewhere. At any rate, thank you for letting me know!

Comment: @EE18 Might not help, but SPICE3 netlist format requires the first line to have an asterisk in front.  It's supposed to be reserved as the netlist name/description, but LTspice might auto-comment it behind the scenes.  I dunno...give it a shot?

Comment: @SteKulov Good thing I forgot: I had to comment out the first line, manually, otherwise LTspice complained (for good reasons). So, I'm surprised that OP gets *that* error message, instead of the one that should be: "*Missing inductance value for Ltspice*" (BTW, it's spelled LTspice).